# XmlSerializer - how to make a type to show as an attribute rather than element itself for arrays

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a problem serializing arrays. The problem I am facing makes it impossible to communicate with SOAP service using Visual Studio generated classes and serialization.
Below is a narrowed down code which ilustrates an issue. I have a class:

```cs
public partial class ArrayOfStrings
    {
        private string[] m_value;
        public string[] value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_value;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_value = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is be initialized like this:

```cs
            var test = new ArrayOfStrings();
            test.value = new string[3];
            test.value[0] = "aaa";
            test.value[1] = "bbb";
            test.value[2] = "ccc";
```

The above values serialize into following output:

```xml
<ArrayOfStrings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <value>
    <string>aaa</string>
    <string>bbb</string>
    <string>ccc</string>
  </value>
</ArrayOfStrings>
```

The problem is that in ArrayOfStrings there is a one 'value' element containing many 'string' elements.
In order to make it work with SOAP it requires it to have many 'value' elements of type 'string' like this:

```xml
<ArrayOfStrings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <value xsi:type="string">aaa</value>
  <value xsi:type="string">bbb</value>
  <value xsi:type="string">bbb</value>
</ArrayOfStrings>
```

Can this be achieved? Is it a problem with converting soap definition into classes or serialization itself?

Comment: You are using the standard XML serialization with array creates two tags : ArrayOfStrings and value.  To get only one level of tags you need in the parent of ArrayOfString an attribute [XmlElement("ArrayOfStrings")] on line before the property.